# Target Laravelista is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to post a comment to my news post using the Laravelista\Comments but I got this error: `Target [Laravelista\Comments\CommentControllerInterface] is not instantiable.`

It was working just fine before, and I didn't change anything except the interface design. Not long after I couldn't post a comments anymore. This is the package I'm using https://github.com/laravelista/comments

Tried adding `Laravelista\Comments\ServiceProvider::class,` to the config\app.php but it didn't do any change.

Is there any solutions?

Comment: Can you add relevant code to your question as it’s difficult to advise as is.

Answer (score 1):

So on Laravel 9 there seems to be an issue getting with `$this->middleware('auth');` in the constructor in the vendor CommentController. A workaround that is working for me is to basically create a custom controller and move the middleware('auth') to the actual routes instead.

1. extend the vendor CommentController
2. Copy the original constructor from there into your new comment controller but remove `$this->middleware('auth');`
3. Copy/paste the store, update, destroy, and reply functions from CommentService in the vendor folder into your new controller.
4. update the config (config\comments.php) to point to your new controller, example `controller' => 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomCommentsController',`
5. copy the routes from vendor into your routes file and chain the middleware('auth') to each route there.
6. Note: I have not tested this with guest commenting enable.

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravelista\Comments\Comment;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Spatie\Honeypot\ProtectAgainstSpam;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laravelista\Comments\CommentController;

class CustomCommentsController extends CommentController 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (Config::get('comments.guest_commenting') == true) {
            $this->middleware('auth')->except('store');
            $this->middleware(ProtectAgainstSpam::class)->only('store');
        } else {
            // $this->middleware('auth');
        }
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // If guest commenting is turned off, authorize this action.
        if (Config::get('comments.guest_commenting') == false) {
            Gate::authorize('create-comment', Comment::class);
        }

        // Define guest rules if user is not logged in.
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            $guest_rules = [
                'guest_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'guest_email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            ];
        }

        // Merge guest rules, if any, with normal validation rules.
        Validator::make($request->all(), array_merge($guest_rules ?? [], [
            'commentable_type' => 'required|string',
            'commentable_id' => 'required|string|min:1',
            'message' => 'required|string'
        ]))->validate();

        $model = $request->commentable_type::findOrFail($request->commentable_id);

        $commentClass = Config::get('comments.model');
        $comment = new $commentClass;

        if (!Auth::check()) {
            $comment->guest_name = $request->guest_name;
            $comment->guest_email = $request->guest_email;
        } else {
            $comment->commenter()->associate(Auth::user());
        }

        $comment->commentable()->associate($model);
        $comment->comment = $request->message;
        $comment->approved = !Config::get('comments.approval_required');
        $comment->save();

        return $comment;
    }

    /**
     * Handles updating the message of the comment.
     * @return mixed the configured comment-model
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Comment $comment)
    {
        Gate::authorize('edit-comment', $comment);

        Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'message' => 'required|string'
        ])->validate();

        $comment->update([
            'comment' => $request->message
        ]);

        return $comment;
    }

    /**
     * Handles deleting a comment.
     * @return mixed the configured comment-model
     */
    public function destroy(Comment $comment): void
    {
        Gate::authorize('delete-comment', $comment);

        if (Config::get('comments.soft_deletes') == true) {
            $comment->delete();
        } else {
            $comment->forceDelete();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles creating a reply "comment" to a comment.
     * @return mixed the configured comment-model
     */
    public function reply(Request $request, Comment $comment)
    {
        Gate::authorize('reply-to-comment', $comment);

        Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'message' => 'required|string'
        ])->validate();

        $commentClass = Config::get('comments.model');
        $reply = new $commentClass;
        $reply->commenter()->associate(Auth::user());
        $reply->commentable()->associate($comment->commentable);
        $reply->parent()->associate($comment);
        $reply->comment = $request->message;
        $reply->approved = !Config::get('comments.approval_required');
        $reply->save();

        return $reply;
    }

}
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('comments', [Config::get('comments.controller'), 'store'])->middleware('auth')->name('comments.store');
Route::post('comments/{comment}', Config::get('comments.controller') . '@reply')->middleware('auth')->name('comments.reply');
Route::delete('comments/{comment}', Config::get('comments.controller') . '@destroy')->middleware('auth')->name('comments.destroy');
Route::put('comments/{comment}', Config::get('comments.controller') . '@update')->middleware('auth')->name('comments.update');
```